# is it possible to write html code inside config file in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel-4

It is a cofig file.I have problem with Mail_body.The mail is sent using this but the problem is that in email I get 'Hello,{{ $name }}', not the value of $name what is in my database. I also put below the controller method.

```
<?php
    'mail_body1' => ('<!DOCTYPE html>
                     <html lang="en-US">
                     <head>
                          <meta charset="utf-8">
                     </head>
                     <body>
                          <h1>Hello, {{ $name }}</h1>

                          <h2>Welcome to Advaita Ashrama, The world of Hope & peace</h2>

                          <p>
                              To subscribe our newsletter please click on the below mentioned link:
                              {{ URL::to("newsletter/verify/" . $confirmation_code) }}.<br/>    
                          </p>
                     </body>
                     </html>')
```

In my controller I use:

```
        $msg = Config::get('ashram.mail_body1');
        Mail::queue('blank',array('msg' => Config::get('ashram.mail_body1'),'name'=>Input::get('name'),'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code), function($message){
            $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'))->subject('Welcome to Advaita Ashrama!');
        });
        print_r($msg);return;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: That's not a good way to do it, create a `emails` directory inside your views. and then when you send an email pass that view, so the mail service can use that view as a email body.

Comment: Message templates should be stored as view files, not HTML strings in a configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config files are string arrays. This means that you can write the HTML in the config file as string and then later include it in your view anywhere you want to.

Comment: "param" => "<p>text</p>"

Comment: But you really shouldn't!

Comment: This answer is advocating **bad practice**. Please do not follow this advice.